# How to answer this interview questions about software engineer

Tags: web, architecture, components, software-design

1. Describe the system architecture in the last 3 projects you worked on. In this case I don't know what system architecture they mean?
2. Which components listed above have you been working on?
3. What frameworks are used during the development of these components?"

Comment: I don't know what you expect us to tell you, only you know what your work history is.

Comment: I don't know what system architecture they actually refer to

Comment: Neither do we. Was your project client/server? Was it based on Ruby on Rails, or maybe Lucky, or Socket.IO+Express? Did it consume web services? Did it stuff data from Excel into SQL Server and was entirely in VBA? Was it a game? What kind? Did it run on DirectX or OpenGL? Did it have network play or just single-player? Turn-based? MMO? Did you employ deep learning? To learn what? With which libraries? Were tensors involved? Maybe a purely console-based application? A UNIX filter? A daemon sitting on a port waiting for connections? Written entirely in C? Combination of Scala and Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a interviewer perspective, they are trying to assess candidates knowledge of overall system they worked up on.

Describing system architecture will help interviewer to know whether candidate knows the big picture of the systems they were part of. The answer could be by explaining the logical architecture(functional view) of application or a component architecture(tech view) depending on context. For a person who is oriented more on infrastructure side, this could be still a bit different, but rarely the case.

Question "on which component have you worked" primarily is intended to understand what exactly was candidates role in project. Explanation on how the component was designed, what technologies are used etc could be answered.

"Frameworks used" would probably tell the interviewer whether candidate was into decision making roles for design or at least can evaluate what is best fit for the need and what is not. Mentioning the frameworks(or libraries or plugins based on tech landscape) used and how that well suit the needs would be a good answer.